# Compare dataframe columns to series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a series, and want to compare the DF column-wise to series.

Dataframe (df) looks like:

```
1   1 4 7
2   2 3 1
3   2 3 9
```

Series (s) looks like:

```
1   3
2   4 
3   2
```

Want to conduct a boolean comparison (where columns values less than series values):

```
1   T F F
2   T T T
3   F F F
```

Of course I could do a loop, but there should be simpler ways to do that?

Comment: Is this pandas?, you should add a tag if so.

Answer (score 6):

Use `lt`, and you can specify an axis.

```
df.lt(s, axis=0)

       1      2      3                   
1   True  False  False
2   True   True   True
3  False  False  False
```

The axis is `1` by default, and using the overloaded operator `<` doesn't give you as much flexibility that way. As DYZ mentioned in a comment, having the `axis` default to `1` here is an exception, because it usually defaults to `0` (in other functions such as `apply` and `transform`).

---

If the series and dataframe indexes don't align nicely, you can still get around that by comparing `s.values` instead.

```
df.lt(s.values, axis=0)

       1      2      3                   
1   True  False  False
2   True   True   True
3  False  False  False
```

Comment: "The axis is 1 by default" - which is somewhat counterintuitive, because for most Pandas functions, axis 0 is the default axis.

Answer (score 3):

```
(df.T<s).T
#       0      1      2
#0   True  False  False
#1   True   True   True
#2  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [:,None], convert you serise

```
df.values<s.values[:,None]
Out[513]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your series before the comparison. Then you can take advantage of `numpy`'s [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature to do the comparison.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}, '1': {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 3}, '2': {1: 7, 2: 1, 3: 9}})
s = pd.Series([3, 4, 2])

s.values.reshape(3, 1) > df

    0       1       2
1   True    False   False
2   True    True    True
3   False   False   False
```